# Using the kaa server, How to save the data from endpoints and how to fetch the data from mongoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb, iot, kaa

I am using the kaa server for Data collections,How to save the data from endpoints and how to fetch the data from mongoDB for objective-c.
My idea is using kaa server to save the values in mongoDB and retrieve.

Comment: using the kaa server it is possiable ?